Origen de destino, utilizar oracle para SSIS visual studio 2022
quiero utilizar una plantilla para realizar ETLS, utilizo SSIS para esto, al momento de realizar el "Data Flow Task" y luego al utilizar asistente de origen no me reconoce Oracle como uno de los orígenes instalados (Vea imagen 1), si se selecciona el checkbox me da 3 opciones para intentar corregir el error, instalando estas herramientas para la conexión, pero por el momento no me han servido



Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=105811

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!
